# Writing to a file in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, file, io, windows-phone-8.1

I am having trouble creating an IO stream.

I found the example below but for some odd reason the `GetResourceStream` is not an available in the Application class.  Am I missing a reference to some API?

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/YOURASSEMBLYNAME;component/Stations.txt", UriKind.Relative));

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
string x = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: are you using VS2012? which project template are you using?

Comment: @kennyzx I am using VS2013.  The template is windows phone app (Blank app)

Comment: That template in VS2013 is targeting WP8.1. Please verify, and update the tag to `Windows-Phone-8.1` if that is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to read a String from your file (as I see in your example), you can use:

```
StorageFile textFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///YOUR FILE PATH"));
String text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(textFile );
```

You can use the methods inside the FileIO class to write to the file as well, both from a text and from a binary buffer.

If you really want to use a buffer stream, you can get it with:

```
IRandomAccessStream accessStream = await textFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: --> This does the trick. I marked the question as been answered.